# Scala Spark Shared connection across all nodes

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

I want to write some data from spark DF to postgres. After searching on stack i found that easiest way of it - to open connection each time I use my prepared statement - and this works fine. But I want to share variable with connection across all nodes.
I get some code from here: https://www.nicolaferraro.me/2016/02/22/using-non-serializable-objects-in-apache-spark/ and wrote this:

```
class SharedVariable[T](constructor: => T) extends AnyRef with Serializable {
   @transient private lazy val instance: T = constructor
   def get = instance 
}

object SharedVariable {
    def apply[T](constructor: => T): SharedVariable[T] = new SharedVariable[T](constructor)}

val dsv = SharedVariable {
   val ds = new BasicDataSource()
   ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
   ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://...")
   ds.setUsername("user")
   ds.setPassword("pass")
ds}
```

But i get an error:

```
error: reference to SharedVariable is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import $line1031857785174$read.SharedVariable
and import INSTANCE.SharedVariable val dsv = SharedVariable {
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your code compiles successfully - maybe you left out some of it?

Comment: I think it's impossible. Postgre connection uses simple tcp/ip. You can't hava shared tcp connection by nodes with different ip addresses.

Comment: You can use  rdd.mapPartitions which allows to share object with records inside a partition